Clarification for Theorem 22 Pugh
This question is regarding the proof of Theorem 22 in Pugh's "Real Mathematical Analysis".

22 Theorem The values of a continuous function defined on an interval $[a, b]$ form
a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$. That is, there exist $m, M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $x \in [a, b]$ we
have $m \leq f (x) ≤ M$.
Proof For $x \in [a, b]$, let $V_x$ be the value set of $f(t)$ as $t$ varies from $a$ to $x$,
$$V_x = \{y ∈ R : \text{for some } t ∈ [a, x] \text{ we have } y = f (t)\}.$$
Set
$$X = \{x ∈ [a, b] : V_x \text{is a bounded subset of } \mathbb{R}\}.$$
We must prove that $b \in X$. Clearly $a \in X$ and $b$ is an upper bound for $X$. Since
$X$ is nonempty and bounded above, there exists in $\mathbb{R}$ a least upper bound $c \leq b$ for $X$. Take $\epsilon = 1$ in the definition of continuity at $c$. There exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $|x − c| < \delta$ implies $|f (x) − f (c)| < 1$. Since $c$ is the least upper bound for $X$, there exists $x \in X$ in the interval $[c − \delta, c]$. (Otherwise $c − \delta$ is a smaller upper bound for $X$.) Now as $t$ varies from $a$ to $c$, the value $f(t)$ varies first in the bounded set $V_x$ and then in the bounded set $J = (f (c) − 1, f (c) + 1)$. See Figure 20.
Figure 20 The value set $V_x$ and the interval $J$
The union of two bounded sets is a bounded set and it follows that $V_c$ is bounded,
so $c ∈ X$. Besides, if $c < b$ then $f (t)$ continues to vary in the bounded set $J$ for $t > c$,contrary to the fact that $c$ is an upper bound for $X$. Thus, $c = b$, $b \in X$, and the
values of $f$ form a bounded subset of $R$.

I get the general ideal of the proof, but I don't get the part "Now as $t$ varies from $a$ to $c$, the value $f(t)$ varies first in the bounded set $V_x$ and then in the bounded set $J = (f (c) − 1, f (c) + 1)$."


A compactness argument would seem more straightforward?

Values of $f$ in $[a, x] $ are bounded. Further values of $f$ in $(c-\delta, c+\delta) $ are also bounded. Just observe that $x\in(c-\delta, c+\delta) $ hence the values of $f$ are bounded in $[a, c+\delta) $ as well.

Note that we have $V_x = f([a,x])$.
Continuity of $f$ in $c$ means that
$$f((c-\delta,c+\delta) \cap [a,b]) \subset J = (f(c)-1,f(c)+1) $$
for some $\delta > 0$.

Since $c$ is the least upper bound for $X$, there exists $\xi∈X$ in the interval $[c−δ,c]$.

[I used $\xi$ instead of $x$ because Pugh uses the same variable $x$ at various places.]
But clearly $(\xi,c] \subset (c-\delta,c+\delta) \cap [a,b]$ so that
$$V_c = f([a,c]) = f([a,\xi] \cup (\xi,c]) = f([a,\xi]) \cup f((\xi,c]) \subset V_\xi \cup J$$
which is the union of the two bounded sets $V_\xi$ and $J$.
If it were true that $c < b$, we could pick $d$ such that $c < d < \min(b,c+\delta)$. Then $(\xi,d] \subset (c-\delta,c+\delta) \cap [a,b]$ dso that
$$V_d = f([a,d]) = f([a,\xi] \cup (\xi,d]) = f([a,\xi]) \cup f((\xi,d]) \subset V_\xi \cup J$$
which is again bounded. Hence $d \in X$ which contradicts the definition of $c$.
